# Flask app with several blueprints route files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to wrap my head around blueprints in Flask. I started a minimal app to try and see how the setup should be, but I am getting an error when I try to run the app.

I have a `venv` with Python 3.9 and the following path values:
`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;FLASK_ENV=development;FLASK_APP=app.py`

Here's the code:
`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask

import routes_home
import routes_test

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(routes_home.home)
app.register_blueprint(routes_test.test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

`routes_home.py:`

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@home.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Home</h1>"
```

`routes_test.py`

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

test = Blueprint('test', __name__)

@test.route('/test')
def test():
    return "<h1>Test</h1>"
```

And here's the abbreviated traceback:

```
  File "/Users/asseeger/CloudStation/appfros.ch/dev/so-samples/py-blueprints/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(routes_home.home)
  File "/Users/asseeger/CloudStation/appfros.ch/dev/so-samples/py-blueprints/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 56, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asseeger/CloudStation/appfros.ch/dev/so-samples/py-blueprints/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1030, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'register'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `routes_home.home` is an attribute lookup, but you only need to reference the module

Comment: Even then, I think you're trying to compress everything way too much. How many things do you want called `home`? You've got a global name that'll just get trampled by the route name. By the time the module is evaluated, which `home` do you think wins in the namespace?

Comment: By just referencing the module you mean something like this: `app.register_blueprint(routes_home)`? Doesn't work neither, I am afraid. Don't get tripped up by `home`–my goal is just to be able to declare routes in separate files. If this is the wrong approach, a hint to the right direction would be appreciated, as I am a pretty noob on Flask obviously :-)

Comment: Sure :) Look again at `routes_home.py` - you have a global name `home =` and then `def home()` so you have conflicting names

Comment: There is an example with the [Python chat room community page](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site/tree/main/sopy), my own website (from my profile, code [here](https://github.com/roganjoshp/portfolio/tree/master/app)) and the [Flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). All use blueprints (with the tutorial introducing them later on in "better app structure")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code suffers from naming confusion in this bit:

```
home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@home.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Home</h1>"
```

Here, `home` start life as a Blueprint, then becomes a function. The last binding wins.

```
app.register_blueprint(routes_home.home)
```

then attempts to register a function instead of a Blueprint. This is what

```
'function' object has no attribute 'register'
```

at the end of the stack trace hints at.

One way forward is to rename the first use to

```
home_bp = Blueprint('home', __name__)
```

(and propagate that name). The other is to rename the function. Your call as to which is clearer to your eye.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks. I can confirm that the naming conflicts are the problem–after changing instantiation of the blueprints to `home_bp` and `test_bp` respectively (I did the same mistake there), everything works as expected.